# python decorator wraps twice?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Encounter a strange problem with python decorator by accident, basically when I directly call decorator function, the original function being wrapped got wrapped twice.

Some simple code to show the problem:

```
def my_deco(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('some code before')
        f(*args)
        print('some code after')
    return wrapper

@my_deco
def original_func(text):
    print   (f'original func print {text}')
```

then command 1):

```
original_func('hello')
```

will print (which is correct by the way):

```
some code before
original func print hello
some code after
```

but command 2):

```
my_deco(original_func)('hello')
```

will print below:

```
some code before
some code before
original func print hello
some code after
some code after
```

Was expecting same results between two commands, but the latter command seems to wrap the original function twice. when I run both commands without parentheses, they both correctly point to the wrapper function, but the results are different once executed with parentheses.

I kind of convinced myself with below logic, but still feel uncomfortable so I am looking for comments or correction on my thinking:

command 1): call original_func -> my_deco -> wrapper -> wrapping + original_func execution

command 2): call my_deco -> wrapper -> wrapping + original_func execution (it is wrapped version)

So it looks like the original_func in command 1) remains as "original" no wrapping; and the original_func in command 2) is "wrapped" version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well... yeah. You wrapped it twice. Why did you apply the decorator twice?

Comment: it is unintentional, meant just once obviously.

Comment: That's because running `my_deco(original_func)('hello')` calls the decorator, than the deocrator again (since the original_func is wrapped by my_deco) and then the original func.

Comment: `original_func` is decorated by `@` then you decorate again with `my_deco..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined `original_func` you use a decorator so python wraped it. In command 2) you wraped it again youself so the result is the function being wraped twice.
If you ran the following, the output should be right:

```py
def original_func(text):
    print   (f'original func print {text}')

my_deco(original_func)('hello')
```

Comment: Yes, your recommended code will work correctly. But I am still puzzled why my two cases are differently, as I said, when run two commands without parentheses, they both point to same wrapper function, and then I should expect same results, but it is not same.

Comment: How do you know they're pointing to the same wrapper function? Did you compare them using te `is` operator?

Comment: @jaydrill: Have you learned about closures yet? The fact that two functions both show up as `wrapper` doesn't mean they're the same function.

Comment: You two (Monica and Roy) have both helped, the two commands  are not same by using 'is' operator and the closure are different as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

Create the decorator:

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapper(num1, num2):
        print('before')
        func(num1, num2)
        print('after')
    return wrapper
```

Call the decorator. This code is incorrect because you are calling the decorator twice - i.e. @decor and decor(add):

```
@decor
def add(num1, num2):
    print(num1 + num2)

add = decor(add)  ## This line will cause it to print a second time. Remove it.

add(3, 88)
```

Call the decorator. This code is correct:

```
@decor
def add(num1, num2):
    print(num1 + num2)

add(3, 88)
```