# Decorator and wrapper execution sequence

Tags: python-decorators

Need help in explaining the execution sequence of a decorator and wrapper function.

I have tried the below code:

```
def DecoratorFun(func):
    # first wrapper function defined in a decorator is returned
    print("DecoratorFun is called")

    def WrapperFun1():
        print("In DecoratorFun and WrapperFun1")
        func()
        print("after WrapperFun1")
    return WrapperFun1

    # WrapperFun2 is not called or returned (ignored and lost ?)
    def WrapperFun2():
        print("In DecoratorFun and WrapperFun2")
        func()
        print("after WrapperFun2")
    return WrapperFun2

@DecoratorFun
def TestFun():
    print("In Test Function")

print("\n")
print(DecoratorFun(TestFun)())
```

I got the below output:

```
DecoratorFun is called
In DecoratorFun and WrapperFun1
In DecoratorFun and WrapperFun1
In Test Function
after WrapperFun1
after WrapperFun1
None
```

However, I am confused with the below sequence. It appears like a recursion. Can someone explain the sequence please?

```
In DecoratorFun and WrapperFun1
In DecoratorFun and WrapperFun1
In Test Function
after WrapperFun1
after WrapperFun1
```

Comment: you can only return **once** from a function. your `WrapperFun2` is indeed lost, as the code definiting it is unreachable. you need to change the structure of your `DecoratorFun` function if you want it to be executed.

Comment: Als, please see the following question [python decorator wraps twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097851/python-decorator-wraps-twice) about the 'recursion' / double execution of your `Wrapperfun1`

Comment: Thnx @Hoodlum. I tried WrapperFun2 just to confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your are decorating `TestFun` on its definition, then wrap it again it at the moment you make a print.
So the call stack will be `DecoratorFun(DecoratorFun(TesFun))`, which makes the print logical.

Instead, do `print(TestFun())`

Comment: Thank you. I was confused as both TestFun and DecoratorFun2(TestFun)() were WrapperFun1 objects and hence expected the same output. But I understood better from the link.